# Spawnsync how to catch unhandled rejection in child

Tags: node.js

I have the following code

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawnSync;
for (const i of list) {
    spawn('/usr/local/bin/node', ['script.js', '-i', i], {stdio: 'inherit'});
}
```

When the child node script has an error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection` the parent crashes.

How to catch this error and continue my loop?